# Exporting partial of prop-types to reuse in components' props

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-props

The following code snippet demonstrates two prop types that I'd like to extract to a separate shared file to reuse in other components.

**./Mycomponent.js**

```js
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string,
  image: PropTypes.string,
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  title: 'some default title',
  description: 'some default description',
  image: './image.jpg'
}
```

I would like to make a generic share props variable, containing only title and description. In order to do this I've created a share props file and extracted the props I'd like to re-use to that file, as you can see in the following example.

**./shared-props.js**

```js
const fooProps = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string,
}
```

Now I'd like to re-use it in **./Mycomponent.js**:

```js
import { fooProps } from './shared-props.js';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  ...fooProps, // <- re-use here
  image: PropTypes.string,
}; 

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  title: 'some default title',
  // defaultProp "title" has no corresponding propTypes declaration.eslintreact/default-props-match-prop-types
  description: 'some default description',
  // defaultProp "description" has no corresponding propTypes declaration.eslintreact/default-props-match-prop-types
  image: './image.jpg'
}

const MyComponent = ({
  title, // "title" is missing in props validation [eslintreact/prop-types]
  description, // "description" is missing in props validation [eslintreact/prop-types]
  image,
}) => {
// ...
```

Now the page renders just fine. Is this just ESLint throwing this error? Or should I be exporting the props differently?

---

Update: It does work when using it as follows:

**./shared-props.js**

```js
const fooProps = PropTypes.shape({
  title: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string,
});
```

**./Mycomponent.js:**

```js
import { fooProps } from './shared-props.js';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  foo: fooProps, // <- only works when adding 'foo'
  image: PropTypes.string,
};
```

But then I'd have to add another level..

Comment: If you destructure the `fooProps` (`MyComponent.propTypes = {
  ...fooProps,
  image: PropTypes.string,
}; `) does the linting error still appear?

Right now you are declaring a prop with name `fooProps`.

Comment: Good one. Tried it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's a limitation of eslint and the rule. One solution could be to destructure fooProps at import and add each prop manually `import {{title, description}} from ...` and `MyComponent.propTypes = { title, description, image:..`